# Entity Framework Manage Runtime Object

Tags: .net, entity

I´ve got a basic entity object, which values are set during runtime.

e.g.:

```
Object object = new Object();
object.property01 = "blabla";
```

Among these propertys are several references to other objects defined by a foreign_key definition.

```
object.object2 = object2;
```

The problem is now that the object doesn´t save the reference. When i hand the object to a viewModel the referenced object always evaluates to null.

Any help regarding how to handle this would be highly appreciated.

edit:
The query i use to get a list of reference objects is as follows:

```
public List<object2> getAll(){
    var object2List = context.object2.ToList();
    return object2List;
}
```

The function i use to create an new object is:

```
private void createNewObject()
{
_newObject = new Object();
_newObject.prop01 = Property01;
_object2databridge.Detach(Object2);
_newObject.object2 = Object2;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show your query code, are you using EF Code First etc? How have you defined the relationships?

Comment: Im using a query to fetch the referenced objects. The user then picks them from a list and the object is assigned to the new object. Because of some context problems object2 is detached from its context before i assign it to the new object.

Comment: Yes, show the configuration and the query code